# Write local Computer Description to AD

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I have one script that writes a specific text to:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters

srvcomment
```

What I then want is that registry entry to be sent to Active directory computer description.

I can pull that registry entry to either a text or CSV file if needs be.

I also can write to active directory using the following:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objSysInfo, strComputerDN, objComputer, strDescr

' Retrieve DN of local computer object in AD.
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strComputerDN = objSysInfo.ComputerName

' Bind to the computer object in AD.
Set objComputer = GetObject("LDAP://" & strComputerDN)

' Assign description and save.
objComputer.description = "test2"
objComputer.SetInfo
```

However, that only inputs what you write in:
objComputer.description = "test2"

What I want to be able to do is pull the information from the registry and send it to Active Directory.

Comment: You should search for a vbscript on the Internet to fetch info from registry, and then merge that code with below code by assigning the value of registry to `objComputer.description` in your current code. You've already given much info; please attempt yourself as you're very close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only piece you're missing is just [reading the value from the registry](https://ss64.com/vb/regread.html):

```
...
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objComputer.description = objShell.RegRead("HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\srvcomment")
...
```